# Run Groovy Script as test - in Gradle and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, groovy

I want to let my developer colleagues code unit (and integration) tests using Groovy Scripts, which they can run inside Eclipse and command line, and which Gradle can run on the CI-server.

I've made a @BaseScript that the scripts declare, which  ..

1. contains a @Test-annotated method `runTest() { run() }`

   implements junit.framework.Test, in the same manner as ScriptTestAdapter does

.. but neither works: Eclipse doesn't pick the scripts up as tests (the "Run as" doesn't contain 'JUnit Test'), and Gradle apparently doesn't pick them up as a test either.

(I just installed the snapshot version of Groovy-Eclipse which contains support for Groovy 2.2, hoping that it would magically work then, which it didn't.)

How can this be achieved?

Comment: And why not just use regular test classes written in Groovy instead of scripts?
Both Gradle and Eclipse should be able to pick them up. By the way, if you are going for groovy in tests, try Spock. You gonna like it, I think.

Comment: First thing to do is to grab a bytecode viewer (or `javap`) and check if the class file generated for the script correctly inherits a method with a `@Test` annotation. Also, `@Test` and `junit.framework.Test` shouldn't be used together, as the former indicates a JUnit 4 test, and the latter a JUnit 3 test.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks, I shall try that. I didn't mix them - I tried them both: First the annotation, then the implementation.

Comment: I agree with topr, you should use the built in Groovy testing support vs. a custom solution. You can find more info on that here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/testing.html . You can get even better testing support using the Groovy based DSL testing framework Spock, an example usage can be found here: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/using-spock-to-test-groovy-and-java-applications/